# R Shiny: numericInputs updating each other using observeEvent

Tags: r, shiny

I have an app in which people can input numbers in two different units:

[image]

I'd like the app to automatically update one of them when the others is changed. This is how I did it:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput(inputId = "km", 
               value   = 1, 
               label   = "kilometres"),
  numericInput(inputId = "m", 
               value   = 1000, 
               label   = "metres"),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$km, {
               updateNumericInput(session = session,
                                  inputId = "m",
                                  value   = input$km * 1000)
               })
  observeEvent(input$m, {
               updateNumericInput(session = session,
                                  inputId = "km",
                                  value   = input$m / 1000)
               })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

It works fine most of the time, but breaks in some cases. For example, if you rapidly change the value by using the mouse wheel, or press and hold one of the arrow buttons. Then, it enters some sort of infinite loop of them updating each other in rapid succession.

Is there a way to stop this infinite loop behaviour?

Comment: I beleive you since I experienced issues like this before yet I cannot replicate the error with this exact minimal example. Something that I found helpfull to some extend in this context has been `throttle()` and `debounce()`. These functions pause the reactivity for a specified number of ms